# JavaScript message system encryption

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to create a message system with JavaScript and PHP / MySQL. I have a form with two input elements (recipient id, message content). I'm using MVC (Zend Framework 1). The form post data is send to my controller and stored in the database.

Now I want to encrypt the message before it is sent. I want to keep it user-friendly, so my idea was to use RSA (private / public key). The idea was that a private key was generated on user log in and stored in the cookies, to make sure that the private key is only on the user's machine. The public key could be stored in the user's table, so that any user, who want to send a message to him, can encrypt the data.

It is important that the key-pair is generated by the user's password. If it's random generated, it would not be possible to use multiple systems to log in, because the private key would change everytime. So that would be the mechanism to make sure, that he will always have the same private key, until he is changing his password.

I tried a few JavaScript libraries. [cryptico](https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico) seemed to be the right choice, because it generates private / public key by password. The problem here is, that I can not store the private key and not even look into the value.

They have an example on the website

```
// The passphrase used to repeatably generate this RSA key.
var PassPhrase = "The Moon is a Harsh Mistress."; 

// The length of the RSA key, in bits.
var Bits = 1024; 

var MattsRSAkey = cryptico.generateRSAKey(PassPhrase, Bits);
```

When I try to output MattsRSAkey, I only get [Object object]. It's the same when I store it in the Cookies. I tried to use JSON.stringify. With this function I can store and look inside MattsRSAKey. But when I want to use it later to decrypt the message, I get an error, that I have no valid public key. I think the private key got broken while storing it. When I read the private key from Cookies I use JSON.parse.

Is there any way to solve my problem? I just want to send encrypted messages from multiple users (public key) to one user (private key). My intention is not to have a secure transport but to store the messages encrypted in the database, so that unauthorized persons can not read it. It is important that I do not only have encryption for one-to-one messaging. This would be easy, because both users only would need to share a password for encryption.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things wrong here.

First, **you're trying to store a Javascript object directly in a cookie**. This won't work: cookies can only store string values. You will need to serialize the key to a string to store it in a cookie; unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the cryptico library exposes any methods to do this, so you will need to either implement a custom serializer, or use another cryptographic library.

Second, **you are storing private cryptographic key data in cookies**. This is perhaps the worst possible place to store this, as cookies are sent to the web server on every request. [Local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is much more appropriate here, as it is only accessible from Javascript code.